# Why "barrel" means "to move quickly"?

Tags: etymology

I just learned that the word "barrel" can be used as a verb.
But I don't associate the container with something "moving quickly".

Is it because the barrel rolling down fast at a slope?

Maybe is there another etymology for it?

Comment: Yes, “barrel rolling downhill” is exactly right.

Comment: As the full OED points out, this metaphoric usage is particularly associated with moving quickly *in a motor car*, so if I heard *He just went barreling past our house*, I'd assume by default that he was ***driving*** past (also by default, I tend to assume *...in a rickety old banger*). Maybe it's just me, but if I knew the subject couldn't possibly be driving, I'd tend to assume he was overweight, clumsy, and liable to collide into other pedestrians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply to move quickly, noisily and/or dangerously, like an out-of-control barrel.

One of my favourite US expressions. Great imagery!

Comment: It also implies “with force”, since a fast moving heavy object has lots of momentum.

Comment: I think British readers like me get used to American verbs of movement like 'carom', 'skitter', and, yes, 'barrel', without much adopting them in our own speech.